# Method and parameter declaration?

Tags: ios, methods, parameter-passing

i have a method

-(void) continueSingle:(id)sender : (Questions*)que{

i am adding this method to a button as a target

```
 [continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(continueButtonSingle:question:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

there is no error or warning but, i am taking an exception unrecognized selector sent to an instance

```
continueButtonSingle:question:
```

i do not understand, i tried different combinations like putting semi colon at the end also, but still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

How would the button know how to send your question and comment id?

What you can do is this:

```
[continueButton addTarget:self action:@selector(continueButtonComment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The parameter you then get passed to your method is the sender, i.e. the button object.

To access the questionId and comment in your method, you could create properties for them and access those in your method.

Comment: but i need the pass parameters which are coming from the other method

Comment: yes, that's why I suggested to create properties for that. I am not sure what exactly you want to do, but i suppose you have some kind of form you want to submit. So you could save the entered comment in a property the moment the user entered it and then you can access that property again when you need it in your `continueButtonComment:` method.

Comment: i really don't get what you mean, i am facing a problem again i update the code in the main question

Comment: It's just not possible to add you custom parameters to the callback. The callback is called by your UIButton instance when a specific event occurs. But UIButton has no knowledge of questionId and comment. Where do you currently set your questionId and comment? Share some more code and I can give you some more details.